# How to import into jenkins Msbuild result

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jenkins, msbuild-4.0

I use build on with the following chain to build several dotnet solution:

```
Jenkins -> batch (cmd) -> MsBuild
```

How to retrieve build result and failure on MsBuild compilation into jenkins and/or Rational team concert build result ?

I have found jenkins plugin to import trx files (tests results) of MSTest.

I expect to find some think equivalent for MSBuild but i don't want to have to define each solution into jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings ng plugin will do it for you.  Install the plugin and then use the following in your publish step :

```
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tools:[msBuild()]
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md

Answer (score 0):

The solution to see the MSBuild output in Jenkins is to install

MSBuild Plugin(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin)

Then, you just need to create a call to it from your pipeline

```
  bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" \"%WORKSPACE%\\Example.sln\" /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=\"%WORKSPACE%\\Example\\Example.sln\" /p:BuildingProject=true"
```

This will show the MSBuild process in the Jenkins console output.